# __autoload function is not working

Tags: php, class, autoload

Here's my code. Im trying to autoload the Sample.php but I'm getting the message : *Unable to load Sample.* What is the problem of this code?

```
function __autoload($class_name) {

   if(file_exists($class_name . '.php')) {
       require_once($class_name . '.php');    
   } 

   else {
    throw new Exception("Unable to load $class_name.");
   }
}

try {
    $a = new Sample();
} 

catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Sample.php

```
Sample {

echo "This is working.";

}
```

Comment: Does the Sample file actually contain a valid class definition?

Comment: Hi @MarkBaker, I tried to do this in the link but still not working. http://www.codeforest.net/autoload-your-classes-in-php

Comment: There is womething wrong with your sample class. Parse error: parse error, expecting `"function (T_FUNCTION)"'

Comment: that isn't PHP code, in the 'Sample` part of your code, check the PHP grammar. (`zend_language_parser.y`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code directly in __autoload function

```
function __autoload($className){
    require 'Sample.php';
}
```

Then show me the result.

Comment: Nothing happened. It didn't display the message : This is working.

Comment: Did you display all errors in settings?Trying some error code like calling an undefined function  showRain() to see the error;

Answer (score 0):

Try this Sample class

```
<?php
class Sample {
   function __construct() {
       echo 'This is working.';
   }
}
```